# Programmatically compile languages with js-lingui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, linguijs

I recently tried to integrate [js-lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) into my react project. The tricky part I can't get right is compiling my languages to js files.

My goal is as follows: I will assemble my languages trough some task running (gulp or webpack maybe). This is as easy as walking through my project, and outputting appropriate json files. However, to use these files they have to be compiled via js-lingui. And I don't know how to do this.

I am aware of *lingui-cli*, which allows me to do this on the cli, but I'm looking for a way to do this programmatically while in my js task runner. In my dream, I could assemble the languages in-memory, pipe them trough the compile mechanism in js-lingui, and output ready to use js files.

I played around a bit with *require('lingui-cli')* (and its submodules), but that was of no use.

Comment: Right now you can import api from 'lingui-cli/dist/api' module, e.g: import { compile } from 'lingui-cli/dist/api/compile'